# How to write a method that takes as input a generic type within a parameterized type?

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me why this is okay:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        test(integers);
    }

    public static void test(List list) {

    }
```

But this creates the error in the comment:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<List<Integer>> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        test(integers);
        //'test(java.util.List<java.util.List>)' cannot be applied to '(java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>)'
    }

    public static void test(List<List> lists) {

    }
```

In my understanding, in both cases, the program casts a parameterized type to a generic type, but it only works in the first case. Why is this and how do I go about making a method with a parameter like the second example that could take any list of lists as input?

Comment: I'll suggest you to read this post https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics
and also this answer of raw types in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is

```
    public static <T> void test(List<List<T>> lists) {

    }
```

or

```
   public static void test(List<? extends List<?>> lists) {
   }
```

Don't *ever* have `List` without a `<` after it, except when importing it.  It has strange properties and removes type safety.  Having `List<List>` puts the compiler into a weird state where it's trying to have some level of type safety and some not.